# Why rgb and not cmy?

Tags: colors, rgb, cmyk

Seeing as how the three primary colors are cyan, magenta and yellow (CMY), why do monitors and almost all the GUI components out there use red, green and blue (RGB)? (If I'm not mistaken, printers use the CMYK model.)

Is there a historical, hardware/software, or other reason for it?

Comment: This discussion is not constructive. Either list a specific target for migration that is valid, or end the discussion here.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: With many common paints, mixing yellow and blue will yield green, but that's a characteristic of the particular paints in question.  The fact that red, yellow, and blue are taught as primary colors is simply a consequence of how many common paints happen to behave.  Even without any chemical reactions, it would be possible to have a paint which looked blue, and a paint which looked yellow, to appear as a medium-dark red when mixed.  For example...

Comment: ...if the "blue" paint contains a relatively sparse suspension of blue particles in a magenta dye, and the "yellow" paint contains a dense suspension of yellow particles in a yellow dye, a mixture of the two would absorb all blue light (because of the yellow dye) and all green light (because of the magenta dye).  The blue particles wouldn't reflect anything of what was left, but the yellow particles would reflect the red light, thus causing the paint to appear red.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There's a difference between additive colors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) and subtractive colors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color).

With additive colors, the more you add, the brighter the colors become. This is because they are emitting light. This is why the day light is (more or less) white, since the Sun is emitting in almost all the visible wavelength spectrum.

On the other hand, with subtractive colors the more colors you mix, the darker the resulting color. This is because they are *reflecting* light. This is also why the black colors get hotter quickly, because it absorbs (almost) all light energy and reflects (almost) none.

Specifically to your question, it depends what medium you are working on. Traditionally, additive colors (RGB) are used because the canon for computer graphics was the computer monitor, and since it's emitting light, it makes sense to use the same structure for the graphic card (the colors are shown without conversions). However, if you are used to graphic arts and press, subtractive color model is used (CMYK). In programs such as Photoshop, you can choose to work in CMYK space although it doesn't matter what color model you use: the primary colors of one group are the secondary colors of the second one and viceversa.

P.D.: my father worked at graphic arts, this is why i know this... :-P

Comment: the OP asked about RYB. Where is the RYB in the answer?

Comment: Because Red-Yellow-Blue doesn't exists, it's Cyan-Magenta-Yellow, that are the subtractive colors. They are already explained.

Answer (score 19):

The difference lies in whether mixing colours results in LIGHTER or DARKER colours. When mixing light, the result is a lighter colour, so mixing red light and blue light becomes a lighter pink. When mixing paint (or ink), red and blue become a darker purple. Mixing paint results in DARKER colours, whereas mixing light results in LIGHTER colours.
Therefore for paint the primary colours are Red Yellow Blue (or Cyan Magenta Yellow) as you stated. Yet for light the primary colours are Red Green Blue. It is (virtually) impossible to mix Red Green Blue paint into Yellow paint, or mixing Red Yellow Blue light into Green light.

Comment: Exact, but you should say "overlaying inks results in darker colours" instead of "mixing paints results in darker colour". Paints are more complex, they can be diffusive, in which case your sentence is wrong (black paint mixed with white diffuse paint is grey, which is lighter than black, whereas any ink mixed with black ink always result in black).

Comment: @galinette I'm sure what you say is perfectly valid, but considering the audience of StackOverflow being IT specialists, I think the difference regarding paints and inks is less relevant as an answer to the question above. I do appreciate the info, though.

Comment: ` It is (virtually) impossible to mix Red Green Blue paint into Yellow paint`. In a similar manner, red seem to be a primary color and cannot(?) be created by mixing others. However, Magenta + Yellow = Red ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)). Is this a contradiction?

Comment: @transang if Magenta and Yellow are available you are using the set [Cyan, Magenta, Yellow] and Red is not available as a primary colour. In that case you need to be able to produce red from the three colours that you have and the combination Magenta + Yellow is what makes a colour closest to Red.

Comment: @Bazz: If I build secondary colors (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow) from primary colors (Red, Green, Blue), then use Magenta + Yellow to build Red. So I have used secondary colors (Magenta, Yellow) to build the primary one (Red). Is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 6):

The basic colours are RGB not RYB. Yes most of the softwares use the traditional RGB which can be used to mix together to form any other color i.e. RGB are the fundamental colours (as defined in Physics & Chemistry texts).

The printer user CMYK (cyan, magenta, yellow, and black) coloring as said by @jcomeau_ictx.
You can view the following article to know about RGB vs CMYK: [RGB Vs CMYK](http://www.copy-cd.biz/dtp-area/RGB-vs-CMYK.jsp)

A bit more information from the extract about them:

> Red, Green, and Blue are "additive
>   colors". If we combine red, green and
>   blue light you will get white light.
>   This is the principal behind the T.V.
>   set in your living room and the
>   monitor you are staring at now. 
>   Additive color, or RGB mode, is
>   optimized for display on computer
>   monitors and peripherals, most notably
>   scanning devices.
>
> Cyan, Magenta and Yellow are
>   "subtractive colors". If we print
>   cyan, magenta and yellow inks on white
>   paper, they absorb the light shining
>   on the page. Since our eyes receive no
>   reflected light from the paper, we
>   perceive black... in a perfect world! 
>   The printing world operates in
>   subtractive color, or CMYK mode.

Comment: it is also to do with colour addition on a (black) screen and colours removal on a piece of (white) paper

Answer (score 1):

the 3 additive colors are in fact red, green, and blue. printers use cmyk (cyan, magenta, yellow, and black).

and as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color explains: if you use RYB as your primary colors, how do you make green? since yellow is made from equal amounts of red and green.

Comment: It's worth noting that paints often exhibit mixing behaviors which are an odd hybrid of additive and subtractive.  Even though mixing yellow and blue inks would yield something close to black, and mixing yellow and blue lights would yield something close to white, mixing yellow and blue paints will often yield green.  For certain kinds of paint, red, blue, and yellow will work well as a set of primary colors, though it's worth noting that two paints which look like e.g. the same shade of yellow, may behave very differently when mixed with a particular blue.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with hardware nor software. Simply that RGB are the 3 primary colours which can be combined in various ways to produce every other colour. It is more about the human convention/perception of colours which carried over.

You may find [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) interesting.